# Sanity Check: Does adding a second voltage divider change the properties of the original?

Tags: voltage-divider, thermistor

I have a thermistor configured in a simple voltage divider on a 5V circuit as follows:

[image: schematic]

I have no control over that part of the circuit.

The problem is that, at normal operating temperatures, that outputs between 2 and 4 volts. I need to read that voltage with a 3.3V microcontroller.

My first though to was to pass the output voltage into another voltage divider:

[image: schematic with added voltage divider]

But now I realize: adding R3&R4 presumably changes the voltage drop across the thermistor, yes? Meaning the output voltage that used to be between 2 and 4 volts is likely shifted *down* since the parallel resistance of R1 combined with R3+R4 is lower.

Am I thinking about this correctly? Is there a better way to drop the voltage below 3.3V without changing the properties of the original divider?

Comment: @dave mankoff The simplest solution is is to lower R1 to get the voltage in an acceptable range. The properties will be similar i.e. shifted/scaled but still monotonic. What's the reason you can't alter the existing divider?

Comment: @MOSFET In short, it's on a separate PCB, and has defined requirements that it's can't be changed - this included. The microcontroller I am adding plugs in externally to read the voltage (among other things). Seems like one way to lower R1 would be to choose an appropriate value for R3+R4, which would have the same effect.

Comment: @davemankoff That won't work - that still requires changing the original divider because any cascaded divider is going to load the original. You need a high input impedance attenuator - opamp gain < 1

Answer (score 8):

You have a few options.

The simplest and most direct is to implement a divider using substantially larger resistors for R3 and R4.  If they add up to 1M or more, the effect on your original divider won't be affected too severely, although there will be a small error.  However, it's important that your A/D have an even higher input impedance.

Alternatively, you could buffer it with an op amp, possibly with the desired (<1) gain already built into it (if it's inverting--if not, you can place the divider on the output).

If you're not using the thermistor for anything else, and don't really care if the voltage at that point changes, you can calculate the new temperature/voltage curve with Excel and translate back in your software.  In that case, R3 and R4 can be combined into a single resistor that works in parallel with R1 to shift the voltage down.

Answer (score 7):

You are completely correct, R3 + R4 is effectively in parallel with R1, and will indeed alter the response of the first divider.

The problem is that R3 and R4 are drawing current from the first divider, a situation which you can mitigate by ensuring R3 and R4 are *much* larger than R1  and the thermistor, by at least a factor of ten. This can only reduce the effect of the second divider on the first, and isn't a great solution. It also has its issues; this will be a very high impedance source for whatever comes next.

The problem is all but eliminated by using an op-amp voltage follower to "buffer" the signal from the first divider. The input of such a buffer draws next to no current, and won't influence the signal there at all. The follower output will have the same potential as its input, but by contrast will be able to sink or source 10s of milliamps into whatever comes next, such as your second divider, without the first divider even knowing anything is connected to it:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fugjmc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

To see the op-amp's input and output currents, you just need to insert some ammeters into those current paths:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbQ78k.png)</sup>

As you can see, input current to the op-amp is tiny, just a few nanoamps, and the first divider is hardly perturbed at all. Op-amp output current is whatever is required by its load (the second divider), 125μA in this case.

<sub>Note: If you are wondering where this 125μA current comes from, the op-amp sources this current from its own power supply. I'd love to show that current using another ammeter on the CircuitLab schematic, but CircuitLab's op-amp simulation is deeply flawed in this respect, and doesn't properly calculate supply currents. The op-amp's power supply current will be whatever the output is drawing, plus whatever the op-amp itself needs for its own internal circuitry.</sub>

You said that your first divider outputs between 2V and 4V, and you simply want to produce a signal compatible with a 3.3V ADC. There are many ways to achieve this. The simplest are shown below centre and right:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvOjjT.png)</sup>

In the middle is the most obvious solution; use the 3.3V supply for the divider, instead of +5V. This will necessarily reduce the maximum possible output potential to +3.3V, resulting in an output between +1.3V and +2.6V (if your claim of +2V to +4V from the existing divider is correct).

On the right I've simply reduced the bottom resistor in the divider from 10kΩ to 3.9kΩ. This results in an output varying between +1.0V and +3.0V. Doing this results in a slightly different curve of voltage vs. temperature, but you would compensate for this is software on the microcontroller.

In this last solution, there's always the possibility that, under extreme temperature conditions, the output could still exceed 3.3V, which means that you should take steps to protect the ADC input. You could exploit the input protection diodes present inside the IC, by simply limiting current through them with an additional resistor:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIT4RB.png)</sup>

The ADC input will have such high input resistance, that it draws almost no current (like the op-amp in the voltage follower solution above). With no current through R3, Ohm's law says there's no potential difference across it, and both left and right ends of R3 will have the same potential. R3 won't significantly affect the signal potential reaching the ADC, but it will prevent significant current flowing if ever the signal does exceed 3.3V.

<sub>Note: R3 may or may not be necessary, as R1 and R2 already limit current. Whether you need R3 is a deeper subject, and requires info from the ADC (microcontroller) datasheet.</sub>

You could employ an op-amp to both scale and *offset*. Here's a design which produces a potential from +0.3V, to +3.0V, just within the ADC's input range, in response to a thermistor resistance going between 15kΩ and 2.5kΩ:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAk2Rn.png)</sup>

[image]

The maths to obtain all those resistor values isn't trivial, and might be the subject for another question, but you have options, lots of them.

Answer (score 5):

All you need to do is reduce the value of R1 to bring the output of the voltage divider into the range you want.
What's that? You can't change R1?
Why would that be a problem if you can externally put another resistor in parallel with R1?

If the output of the existing divider ranges from 2V to 4V with R1 = 10k, then the value of the thermistor must go from 15k to 2.5k over the temperature range of interest.
To achieve a range of about 1.25V to 3.3V over the same temperature range would require R1 = 5k.
So how do you turn a 10k resistor into a 5k resistor?
You put another 10k in parallel with it externally (on the input to your MCU).

Comment: The only problem is, there will now be double the current passing through the NTC. Which might, or might not be a problem.

Answer (score 5):

First off, you are right (as everyone clearly points out) that a second voltage divider will load down your existing circuit.

You've got a lot of useful responses. I've one additional thought to add. Mostly, because of its simplicity and it allows you to use your voltage divider idea without an opamp.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fue3fK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

\$R_1\$, \$R_2\$, \$Q_1\$, and \$Q_2\$ are arranged so that the \$R_x\$ and \$R_y\$ voltage divider are buffered and therefore won't load down your sensor output. The base of \$Q_1\$ will only draw about \$1\:\mu\text{A}\$. So it does not mess with the sensor much. (On the order of \$10\:\text{mV}\$, though you can alter \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$ to make this even less, if desired.) The two BJTs are also arranged so that their respective \$V_{_\text{BE}}\$ values compensate for each other (mostly -- I also tried to keep their respective current densities about the same, as well) and this reduces the impact of operating temperature, though there will still be some relative offset differences for unmatched junkbox BJTs.

Regardless, you can now fairly freely set \$R_x\$ and \$R_y\$ as desired to get the voltage into the range you want.

It's a really simple circuit and takes only a few parts. That's its strength. You can cobble it up very quickly and test it. However, how well it satisfies your needs is another issue that you will have to work out.

*(I left \$V_{_\text{CC}}\$ unspecified for now as I'm not sure if you want to use \$5\:\text{V}\$ there, or something else. But \$V_{_\text{CC}}\ge 5\:\text{V}\$ here.)*

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use a voltage follower circuit with an opamp. The opamp provides a high impedance to the thermistor so it doesn't put a load on the voltage which is what you are trying to measure.

Typically a differential amp is used with 4 resistors, you can also provide some gain. The equations to set this up can be difficult but if you need better than 1C accuracy then it's the better way to go.

https://www.ti.com/lit/an/sboa323a/sboa323a.pdf?ts=1706627647315&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.bing.com%252F

I was able to use differential amplifiers to measure 10mK's

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it possible to connect the thermistor to the ground and the resistor to 5V? You'd get 1..3V output, within the input range of your ADC. The signal would be inverted, but that can be compensated in the firmware.

Alternatively, the thermistor could be connected to a 3.3V supply. The signal would be lower, but that too can be compensated in software.

If values above 3.3V are not interesting, the only concern is protecting the MCU from excess voltage, you need not worry too much. Just make sure that the current is limited to safe levels and let the protection diodes in the MCU do their job. Take the first schematic and connect another resistor between the output and the MCU. You can even add a cap and create a low-pass filter with the same resistor to filter out noise.

Considering your second circuit, the problem is that the R3/R4 divider would load the divider formed by R1 and the thermistor and distort the output signal. In fact R1 is not necessary here; you can achieve the same output voltage by removing R1 and adjusting R3/R4. It's basically the classical wye-star transformation.

If I were you, I'd consider using an integrated digital thermometer like the DS1820. There are other variants with different 1-wire protocols, I2C and so on. They're easier to interface, are inherently very accurate without the need of calibration, all your analog signal concerns go away.